# How to Customize the NetSuite Calculate Shipping Button

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

How can I customize the Calculate Shipping button (the calculator icon) on Sales Orders under the Shipping tab? I've written my own app using the UPS API and I would like to fire that instead of the native NetSuite shipping calculator. **So how can I make the Calculate Shipping button fire my custom code?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry but there is no way to do that via API. You could hack it but probably more trouble than it's worth.

to make your custom calc work:

- Associate it with a shipping method (or methods) that have flat rate of $0. If you don't use $0 then NS will re-apply the flate rate charge at various inopportune times.
- when something changes trigger the API lookup OR
- add a button on the SO form that you can click.

You can also add buttons various other ways with more or less degrees of control. One way is to include an inlinehtml field containing the html for a button and have a script show that when one of your associated methods is selected. I'd back that up with a save page client or before submit user event script to re-calc the value when needed.

When I've done this sort of thing I've made a hash of the shipping address and item ids and quantities and stored that as a body level field. Then you can re-calc the hash in a before submit event and call your API only when the hash has changed.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thank you so much for the swift reply and tips!

Answer (score 1):

An another way would be to add a new button using

```
form.getSublist('item').addButton(name, label, script);
//button would be added in item sublist section
```

In your script parameter specify the `onclick` script, the `onclick` script would be a client side javascript in which you should be able to get SO lines and then fire a AJAX to your suitelet [even `nlapiReuqstURL` should work smoothly here] which in turn can make calls to your UPS APIs and fetch the rates from there.

Now, the challenge remains is getting rid of the natural calculate shipping button. Probably, you can make it a zero cost one or make the label of new button more appealing to click over the standard one.

Comment: Yeah, I actually have the UPS request working. I have my Client script calling a Suitelet which calls UPS then displays the shipping rate in the "shippingcost" field. Right now, I'm just using a Custom Button to call my code, but obviously I'd prefer to use the calculator button. I'm thinking that I will hide the Shipping tab and then make a new custom tab and add a custom button on that tab like you suggest.

Comment: yeah, thats the thing to hide the button you got to hide the hole tab/sublist. Would be great if NS gives some API to hide the std. sublist buttons

Comment: Heya, @prasun, I'm finally getting back to this button thing and I have a question for you. The code you presented adds a button to a sublist, but there's no way in determining where that button is, correct? It just appears at the top of the sublist, right? I want to add a button on the sublist, but I'd like to put it wherever I want, much like that calculator button. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can't specify your own position,  you got to rely on the mercy of Netsuite api,  you could do DOM hacks but, that is NOT recommended as can break anytime